# Keyboard shortcut to "click" text highlighted with Ctrl+F

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer, mouse-click

I spend a lot of time hunting for specific links within massive pages of text with Ctrl+F, then opening those links. I would like to do this entirely with keyboard shortcuts. I have this figured out for Chrome, but need to know how to do the same in Internet Explorer.

In Chrome:

- Ctrl+F to search for specific text, enter to toggle between results
- Ctrl+Enter "clicks" the selected text.

In IE:

- Ctrl+Enter does nothing, sadly.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> has selected a result, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the Find search box.

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Ha! But of course! That was easy, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :). If it solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you!